# ifelse with no else

Tags: r

Basically in SAS I could just do an if statement without an else. For example:

```
if species='setosa' then species='regular';
```

there is no need for else.

How to do it in R? This is my script below which does not work:

```
attach(iris)

iris2 <- iris
iris2$Species <- ifelse(iris2$Species=='setosa',iris2$Species <- 'regular',iris2$Species <- iris2$Species)
table(iris2$Species)
```

Comment: An `if` statment without the `else` is : `if(iris2$Species == 'setosa') { do your thing }`

Comment: `iris2$Species[iris2$Species == 'setosa'] <- 'regular'`. Also don't use `attach`. (You put the line `attach(iris)` here and (a) don't make any use of its result in your question and (b) its results can often cause bugs so you shouldn't use it at all.)

Comment: @SymbolixAU - That will likely be problematic, since `iris2$Species` has length greater than 1.  Surprised no one mentioned that yet.

Comment: @RichScriven - indeed you're correct - I suppose a better, more generic comment should have been `if( condition ){ do your thing}`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A couple options. The best is to just do the replacement, this is nice and clean:

```
iris2$Species[iris2$Species == 'setosa'] <- 'regular'
```

`ifelse` returns a vector, so the way to use it in cases like this is to replace the column with a new one created by `ifelse`. *Don't do assignment inside `ifelse`!*

```
iris2$Species <- ifelse(iris2$Species=='setosa', 'regular', iris2$Species)
```

But there's rarely need to use `ifelse` if the *else* is "stay the same" - the direct replacement of the subset (the first line of code in this answer) is better.

---

#### New factor levels

Okay, so the code posted above doesn't actually work - this is because `iris$Species` is a `factor` (categorical) variable, and `'regular'` isn't one of the categories. The easiest way to deal with this is to coerce the variable to `character` before editing:

```
iris2$Species <- as.character(iris2$Species)
iris2$Species[iris2$Species == 'setosa'] <- 'regular'
```

Other methods work as well, (editing the factor levels directly or re-factoring and specifying new labels), but that's not the focus of your question so I'll consider it out of scope for the answer.

---

Also, as I said in the comments, don't use `attach`. If you're not careful with it you can end up with your columns out of sync creating annoying bugs. (In the code you post, you're not using it anyway - the rest runs just as well if you delete the `attach` line.)