# Replacing conditional values with previous values in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data on organism survival as a function of time. The data is constructed using the averages of many replicates for each time point, which can yield a forward time step with an increase in survival. Occasionally, this results in a survivorship greater than 1, which is impossible. How can I conditionally change values greater than 1 to the value preceeding it in the same column?

Here's what the data looks like:

```
>df
 Generation Treatment  time    lx
 1 0                  1     0 1    
 2 0                  1     2 1    
 3 0                  1     4 0.970
 4 0                  1     6 0.952
 5 0                  1     8 0.924
 6 0                  1    10 0.913
 7 0                  1    12 0.895
 8 0                  1    14 0.729
 9 0                  2     0 1    
10 0                  2     2 1
```

I've tried mutating the column of interest as such, which still yields values above 1:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(Generation, Treatment) %>%
  mutate(lx_diag = as.numeric(lx/lag(lx, default = first(lx)))) %>% #calculate running survival
  mutate(lx_diag = if_else(lx_diag > 1.000000, lag(lx_diag), lx_diag)) #substitute values >1 with previous value

>df1
Generation Treatment  time    lx lx_diag
 1 12                 1     0 1       1    
 2 12                 1     2 1       1    
 3 12                 1     4 1       1    
 4 12                 1     6 0.996   0.996
 5 12                 1     8 0.988   0.992
 6 12                 1    10 0.956   0.968
 7 12                 1    12 0.884   0.925
 8 12                 1    14 0.72    0.814
 9 12                 1    15 0.729   1.01 
10 12                 1    19 0.76    1.04
```

I expect the results to look something like:

```
>df1
Generation Treatment  time    lx lx_diag
 1 12                 1     0 1       1    
 2 12                 1     2 1       1    
 3 12                 1     4 1       1    
 4 12                 1     6 0.996   0.996
 5 12                 1     8 0.988   0.992
 6 12                 1    10 0.956   0.968
 7 12                 1    12 0.884   0.925
 8 12                 1    14 0.72    0.814
 9 12                 1    15 0.729   0.814 
10 12                 1    19 0.76    0.814
```

I know you can conditionally change the values to a specific value (i.e. [ifelse with no else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427343/ifelse-with-no-else)), but I haven't found any solutions that can conditionally change a value in a column to the value in the previous row. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I realized that `mutate` and `if_else` are quite efficient when it comes to converting values. Instead of replacing values in sequence from the first to last, as I would have expected, the commands replace all values at the same time. So in a series of values >1, you will have some left behind. Thus, if you just run the command:

```
SurvTot1$lx_diag <- if_else(SurvTot1$lx_diag > 1, lag(SurvTot1$lx_diag), SurvTot1$lx_diag)
```

over again, you can rid of the values >1. Not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: In `df`, `Treatment` is 0 but in `df1`, `Treatment` is 12, how?

Comment: Which column in `df`, refers to `survivorship`?

Comment: @Sonny, the columns in `df1` are a subsample of the entire data set. The `Generations` range from 0:25. The `Treatment` is the 3rd column and ranges from 1:4. Survivorship is the column labeled `lx` and `lx_diag`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a very ugly solution to me, but I couldn't think of anything else:

```
df = data.frame(
  "Generation" = rep(12,10),
  "Treatent" = rep(1,10),
  "Time" = c(seq(0,14,by=2),15,19),
  "lx_diag" = c(1,1,1,0.996,0.992,0.968,0.925,0.814,1.04,1.04)
)


update_lag = function(x){
  k <<- k+1
  x
}

k=1

df  %>% 
  mutate(
    lx_diag2 = ifelse(lx_diag <=1,update_lag(lx_diag),lag(lx_diag,n=k))
  )
```

Comment: This works to remove all the values >1, but I seem to still run into trouble with replacing them with the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data from @Fino, here is my vectorized solution using base `R`

```
vals.to.replace <- which(df$lx_diag > 1)
vals.to.substitute <- sapply(vals.to.replace, function(x) tail( df$lx_diag[which(df$lx_diag[1:x] <= 1)], 1) )
df$lx_diag[vals.to.replace] = vals.to.substitute
df

   Generation Treatent Time lx_diag
1          12        1    0   1.000
2          12        1    2   1.000
3          12        1    4   1.000
4          12        1    6   0.996
5          12        1    8   0.992
6          12        1   10   0.968
7          12        1   12   0.925
8          12        1   14   0.814
9          12        1   15   0.814
10         12        1   19   0.814
```